# Excel 2010 VBA Code not running

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm currently using Excel 2010 and am trying to run some code I put together in VBA for Applications (after hitting alt+F11).  I typed up the code in a notepad that appeared after double clicking the project I wanted to work on.  I also saved everything as Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm).

I am trying to color the backgrounds of Column D either green or red if columns S, T, and U meet the criteria.  If the columns all have a value of 0 then Cell D should be colored green.  If not, it should be colored red.

```
Sub GreenOrRed()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 2 To i = 27293
    If (Cells(i, "S").Value = 0 And Cells(i, "T").Value = 0 And Cells(i, "U").Value = 0) Then
        Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    Else
        Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 9
    End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

The code runs and doesn't throw any error but it also doesn't do anything.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just so that you can understand **why** the `For` loop was valid but didn't do anything ... your statement is effectively `For i = 2 To (i = 27293)`.  At the loop initialisation `i` is 0, so `i = 27293` equates to `False`.  `False`, when coerced to an `Integer`, is 0.  So your statement then becomes `For i = 2 To 0`.  Because 2 is already greater than 0, control immediately jumps to the statement after the `Next i`.

Comment: Hey Everyone, thank you for the responses.  I found out that my issue was that I wasn't putting the "Worksheets(Sheet).Cells" before all the cells.  Once I did that I was able to get my stuff to work.  I also changed the function from a For loop to a While loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are using counter in For loop incorrectly. It should be like this...

```
For i = 2 To 27293
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed `For condition`.
Try this:-

```
Sub GreenOrRed()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 2 To 27293
    If (Cells(i, "S").Value = 0 And Cells(i, "T").Value = 0 And Cells(i, "U").Value = 0) Then
        Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    Else
        Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 9
    End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

```
Sub GreenOrRed()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range
    Set rr = Range("D1:D27293")

    For Each r In rr
        If r.Offset(0, 15).Value = 0 And r.Offset(0, 16).Value = 0 And r.Offset(0, 17).Value = 0 Then
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Else
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = 9
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider setting one (or two) conditional formatting rules.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GreenOrRed()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 9
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and(sum($S2)=0, sum($T2)=0, sum($U2)=0)")
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                .StopIfTrue = True
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I've used individual SUM functions to ensure that any text returns a numerical value of zero.

Alternate AutoFilter method.

```
Sub GreenOrRedFiltered()
    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 18)
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 9
            .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=0, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=vbNullString
            .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=0, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=vbNullString
            .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=0, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=vbNullString
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```